# .NET Framework viewmodel into seperate Javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

I have a basic question i guess...
I would like to SoC my design. I have the

- testController.cs
- testViewModel.cs
- testView.cshtml
- testScript.js

i generate some data in the controller, filling the testViewModel and passing it to the Razor view
inside the razor view i can just use

```
<script>
    var someVariable = @Model.someVariable;
</script>
```

this is working just fine, untill i want to move my javascript code into a seperate js file.

What is the best way to get the data in a variable that is residing in the javascript file?

That is actually the basic question, and secondly once this is working
i would like to use VueJs in the same manner, in a seperate file.

But i don't know how to get the data from the razor view into the vue data variable.

what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's necessarily a "best practice", since different solutions will be optimal for different scenarios. With that being said, one way I tend to do this is by using the "revealing module pattern" with IIFEs. So it may look like this:

**SomeScript.js**

```js
var SomeModule = (function () {
    var someVariable = null;

    return {
        // someExternalVar will be passed from the caller
        init: function (someExternalVar) {
            someVariable = someExternalVar;
        }
    };
})();
```

Then in the Razor view:

**MyRazor.cshtml**

```html
<!-- import your SomeScript.js -->

<!-- other stuff -->

<script>
    SomeModule.init(@Model.someVariable);
</script>
```

I'm sure you could expand on this pattern to instantiate Vue using the parameter(s) passed to `SomeModule.init()`.